# 74ls148 to 7447 to 7-segment connection. Why is it showing output 0-7 only

Tags: adc, comparator, 7segmentdisplay

We have a project that requires the use of comparators, 74LS148(For Flash ADC), 74LS47 and a 7-segment digit display to show numbers 0-9. The problem is that it only shows an output of 0-7 in the simulator:
[image: 148 to 08 to 47 to 7segment]

The comparator part before the 74LS148 is an LM339 with a pull-up resistor of 3k ohms and it goes like this:
[image: Full]

and the close up for the comparator part is like this:
[image: Pull-up res]

I don't understand why it is only showing 0-7 and doesn't include 8 and 9. I also do not understand where to put 1Y from the 74LS08 (In the datasheet of 74LS148, it is called the "Priority Flag"). It would be good to know why and how to make sure it outputs 0-9 in 7-segment display

Edit: Made it look cleaner

[image: Full w/ Comparator]

[image: Closeup of Comparator]

Comment: Turn off the grid, man. Turn off the grid. Actually, the first and third schematics are reasonably legible but the grid is a distraction. You have a short on the inputs of U3A.

Comment: Measure things.

Comment: What do you mean by measure things?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. Cleaned-up schematic.*

I didn't analyze the whole thing but the inputs to U3A look odd. You have them connected together. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes it is intentional because that is meant to be part of the Flash ADC part of the project Edit: I added a cleaned up schematic on the original post for better clarification :)

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you connect the two inputs to a comparator. A few tips: (1) Your schematic editor should allow you to create some sort of net for your +5 V rail. Use that and you can eliminate many of the cross-over wires. This will improve legibility greatly. (2) Can you add a label to each comparator so we can understand its function?

Comment: I will try do that and update the main post. Though I have a question regarding your first statement. What are the inputs supposed to be for the comparator for Flash ADC??? I always thought the comparator chooses which of the two inputs it recieved is bigger and will emit an output of either +Vsat and -Vsat but I may be wrong. . .

Comment: I don't know much about flash ADC but if you apply the same signal to U3A IN+ and IN- what do you expect the comparator to do? The IN+ is neither greater or less than IN-. It could switch either way if there is a slight difference in the input sensitivity. It may oscillate if the inputs are really closely matched.